# Click on two Table cells highlight their content and store their values in variables

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I am getting a Table from a database like this (row numbers may vary):

```
|Player 1|Player 2|
-------------------
|Danny   |Danny   |
|John    |John    |
|Mary    |Mary    |
```

I want to select two names, one from each Player column, and store them in two variables, say player1_id and player2_id which I will later use to insert data into the database. I also want to highlight the names when they are clicked. The highlight and the associated variable value should change when I click on another name.

For example, let's say I click on Danny and John from Player 1 and Player 2 respectively. These two names should get highlighted and the variables should get player1_id = "Danny" and player2_id = "John". If I change my mind and click on Mary on the Player 2 column, Mary should get highlighted, John should lose its highlight and player2_id should change to "Mary"

So far I managed to sort of getting only the highlight part (but when I click more than one names all stay highlighted). Could anyone point me to a correct direction, please?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nlamp/8d4pk62j/) is the JSFiddle code of what I have so far

Answer (score 1):

try this: https://jsfiddle.net/dunsondog109/behcgwLf/7/

```
function inputClickHandler(e){
    e = e||window.event;
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var tdElm = e.target||e.srcElement;
    var tdIndex = tdElm.cellIndex;
    var numberOfColumns = 2;
    if(tdElm.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(46, 204, 64)'){
        tdElm.style.backgroundColor = '';
    } else {
        for (var i=0;i<all.length;i++) {
            if (i%numberOfColumns==tdIndex%numberOfColumns) {
                // It is in the same column
                all[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
            }
        }
        tdElm.style.backgroundColor = '#2ECC40';
    }
}
```

You need to reset all the tds in your column first and then set the td that was clicked

Comment: OK, this works regarding the highlighting part. Any suggestions how to assign the highlighted names into the two variables (player1_id and player2_id) in order to use this into a later php statement to insert those names into a mysql database?

Comment: You can cycle through the tds and check the background-color and index again. If the background-color is '#2ECC40 then you know it is the selected name then take (i%numberOfColumns)+1 to determine if it should go to player1_id or player2_id. I don't see any php code in your fiddle so I don't know what to modify. I'm sure you've already google php insert command and made an attempt to insert into your database already.

Comment: Here is the complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/nlamp/97adhws5/ In a nutshell, I have an entry form with 4 fields in which the user enters 4 values: player1_id, score1_id, etc. When I press the button type="submit" these data get correctly into the database with the prepared insert statement. What I want however is to get rid of the two fields for player1_id and player2_id in the form, or modify the code in such a way that these values will be collected from the two pressed and highlighted td's in the table we are creating with your javascript example.

Comment: Could you please help me out a bit more?  Why do I have to cycle through tds again? Couldn't I just add code after your last command when you set the `tdElm.style.backgroundColor = '#2ECC40';`?  For example, when I add `alert(this.textContent);` after the above line in your script, a pop up message displays the name of the td we have just clicked. But how to store the name shown in the pop up in a php variable? I tried using `var player1_id = this.textContent;` (i.e. without the alert) in a function but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will not help you, but this is what I created for fun ...
As I'm jQuery user I find it difficult to list the table for any actions using plain javascript ... I would prefer having list of players in some object, draw the table based on that list. Instead of adding css to table cell i would add class like active and then just easily remove / move that class to different player. Maybe even adding some classes or other data-attributes to the table cells to help identify correct row / cell ... Anyway, everything is possible, but with this design you will not get far with your project I think. Good luck.

```js
var Game = function() {
  
 var players = {};
  var table = document.querySelector('#myTable');
  var rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  
 
  function uncheckPlayers(col) {
    for ( var i=0; i<rows.length; i++ ) {
      var tds = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td');
      for ( var x=0; x<tds.length; x++ ) {
        if ( col === x ) {
          tds[x].style.backgroundColor = '';
        }
      }
    }

  }
  
  for ( var i=0; i<rows.length; i++ ) {
      var tds = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td');
      for ( var x=0; x<tds.length; x++ ) {
        tds[x].addEventListener('click', function() {
          var id = x;
          return function() {
            uncheckPlayers(id);
            players[id] = new Player(id, this.innerText);
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            console.log(players);
          }  
 
        }(x));
      }
  }

  
}

var Player = function(id, name) {
 this.name = name;
  this.id = id;
  this.score = 0;
  console.log(this);
};

var Game = new Game();
```

```html
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Find table cell value on cell (table) click using JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        Click on table below to select Players.
        <br />
        <br />
    </center>
    <table align="center" id="myTable" border="1" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <tr>
      <th>Player 1</th><th>Player 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Danny</td><td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td><td>Danny</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td><td>Mary</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this works nicely with the simple JSFiddle example I've provided it doesn't do anything with the actual application I am developing. Could this be because I am creating the Table from an sql query? I like your idea about storing the names in a list first. I will try this and come back.

Comment: I am trying to experiment with your example but can't get it to work to do the highlighting. Following your suggestion I have now the names in an array like this: `array = ([Danny] => 1 [John] => 2 [Mary] => 3)` and the Table is created like this: `echo "<table id='myTable'> <tr><th>Player 1</th><th>Player 2</th</tr>"; 
 foreach($array as $key=>$row)  {echo "<tr>";echo "<td>" . $key . "</td>";echo "<td>" . $key . "</td>";  echo "</tr>";}echo "</table>";` But it doesn't work. But when I use the Table you provided it works. Is it because I use echo? By the way, is your example JS or JQuery?